# VPN for gaming using Raspberry Pi/any other hardware for Civ 5

Tags: server, vpn, games

So I'm looking at some tutorials on making a VPN server using the Raspberry Pi B. I'm curious, how do you think the performance would be if I had max 5 connections to the VPN for playing Civ 5?

I'm most likely going to try it out but if there are any other recommendations for hardware please suggest!

This is the tutorial I was looking at:
http://readwrite.com/2014/04/10/raspberry-pi-vpn-tutorial-server-secure-web-browsing/

Thank you!

Kim

Answer (score -1):

Sorry to say this but performance will probably be terrible. Eth0 almost never gets a 100mbs, USB adapters are not much of an option either (you will need two NICs or wifi + Ethernet.) On top of that you will probably not get over 20mbs if you use say, openvpn.

Comment: Care to give reasons/facts to back up the assertions made here?